# "updateDet" shouldnt recognize as keyword "update"

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, parser-combinators, combinators

With this code

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

class TestKeywords  extends JavaTokenParsers {

  def keywords: Parser[String] = "update"

  def identifier: Parser[String] = not(keywords) ~> """[a-zA-Z0-9_$#]+""".r

  def script: Parser[Any] = repsep(identifier,",")
}

object TestKeywordsApp extends TestKeywords with App {
  val cmd = """updateDet,update"""
  parseAll(script,
    cmd.stripMargin) match {
    case Success(lup, _) => println(lup)
    case x => println(x)
  }
}
```

i get error

> [1.1] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but`u' found
>
> updateDet,update

How to fix it? updateDet shouldnt recognize as keyword

scala 2.10.2

Comment: word boundaries perhaps

Comment: To expand, you've said that `identifier` is `not(keywords)` followed by some characters. But `updateDet` isn't that - it does start with a keyword. Perhaps you should declare that a keyword ends with a word boundary (regex `\b`)?

Answer (score 0):

word boundaries perhaps
                    – Amit Joki

To expand, you've said that `identifier` is `not(keywords)` followed by some characters. But `updateDet` isn't that - it does start with a keyword. Perhaps you should declare that a keyword ends with a word boundary (regex `\b`)?
                    – lmm